# CSS comma separated selectors placeholder

Tags: css, placeholder

in my situation the following CSS code is not applied anywhere, IE, Firefox, Chrome, Edge

```
#products input::-moz-placeholder,
#products input::placeholder,
#products input:-ms-input-placeholder,
#products input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
```

But this code works for every browser.

```
#products input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
}

#products input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}

#products input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
```

Why the first code snippet is not working ? What am I missing.

Comment: because for each browser there is a wrong one ignored .. so if you put them together all of them will be ignored

Comment: Thanks didn't know that: `Note: don't mix the vendor prefix selectors (-moz, -webkit, -ms, ...). Chrome for example won't understand "-moz-" and then ignores the whole selector`